# TFS 2013 build activity GetLocalPath not working

Tags: tfs, build, tfsbuild

It seems that no matter what I pass into the **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Core.GetLocalPath** build activity it always returns the same thing as a result.

I have tried passing in both full file paths and just directories.

Below are two example activity logs which show this incorrect behavior:

[Directory path](http://pastebin.com/NZCJFReQ)

[Full path](http://pastebin.com/fiLSB8s9)

I have verified that the server directory is mapped in the build definition and everything should be set up correctly.

Am I doing something wrong or is this just a bug? If so, is there any way to work around this? In the past it was possible to use ConvertWorkspaceItem but the Workspace variable is no longer available.

Comment: I'd recommend against modifying XAML build process templates. They're a huge pain to debug and maintain. Beyond that, TFS2015 will have a brand new build system, deprecating the XAML build process templates.

Comment: Unfortunately I need this now and TFS2015 is still a ways away :P

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error. GetLocalPath just returning whatever you give as output. I resolved it by placing the GetLocalPath activity inside Run on Agent scope and it started working fine.

Placing the same activity outside Run on Agent reproduced the error.